# Convert time "28:45" to "4:45" MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I'm looking for a way to order my results based on the actual time. In my table yo can see values like:

```
 1,23:45
 2,9:45
 3,27:43
```

When I do a query I would like to know how to order them based on their actual 24 hour time.

Ex:

```
3,3:43
2,9:45
1,23:45
```

Notice how it changes 27:43 to 3:43, and creates the order.

---

Where I am using it, in this query:

```
SELECT    *,COALESCE(ADDTIME(s.`departure_time`,SEC_TO_TIME(rt.delay)),s.`departure_time`) as `rt_time` FROM `stop_times` s INNER JOIN `trips` t ON s.`trip_id` = t.`trip_id` INNER JOIN `stops` st ON st.`stop_id` = s.`stop_id` INNER JOIN `routes` r ON r.`route_id` = t.`route_id` LEFT JOIN `rt_trips` rt ON t.`trip_id` = rt.`trip_id` where (s.`stop_id` = 'CB900') and ( ( s.`departure_time` >= '00:50' and s.`departure_time` <= '05:50') OR ( s.`departure_time` >= '24:50' and s.`departure_time` <= '29:50') ) and (s.`pickup_type` = '0') and (t.`service_id` IN ('removed to make it easier')) HAVING (`rt_time` BETWEEN '01:50' and '05:50' ) ) OR ( `rt_time` BETWEEN '25:50' and '29:50'  ) ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Explanation:
Information is a transit schedule, that may go forward onto the next day which may be a saturday. So, times may become 25:50, where that means 1:50 the next day.

Thanks
Cyrus

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What SQL are we dealing with? What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of storing some weird format you should [normalize your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post, mySQL (myIsam), it's an annuity based transit schedule (that repeats itself, one schedule for each weekday, one schedule for a saturday). But it overlaps, during the night hours.

Therefore, I need to somehow order it to adjust when the time says 25:50 and cover it to 1:50

Comment: your can use order by cast(substring_index(col,',',1) as unsigned) desc,STR_TO_DATE(substring_index(col,',',-1),'%H:%i') desc

Comment: @CyrusKafaiWu - Please check the answers and accept the one worked for you. If not working then mention the exact problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, if you just want to get a value between 0 and 24 hours, then I would do:

```
select concat(mod(substring_index(time_column, ':', 1) + 0, 24), ':',
              substring_index(time_column, ':', -1)
             )
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this, to insure proper ordering of the values. Just an added LPAD

concat(LPAD(mod(substr(`departure_time`,1,INSTR(`departure_time`, ':')-1),24),2,'0'),substr(`departure_time`,INSTR(`departure_time`, ':'),3) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this function on the time_column

```
concat(mod(substr(time_column,1,INSTR(time_column, ':')-1),24)
       ,substr(time_column,INSTR(time_column, ':'),3)
       )
```

You might need to cast date to string to integer, do the maths, and again cast it to time. But the fiddle version seems to work properly on varchar to integer conversion. Check this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff60f9/1